# Como importar librerias en Perl?

Tags: programación-funcional, perl, lenguaje-compilado

Mi pregunta es simple y quiza la solucion tambien...
Ando aprendiendo Perl, se como funciona python, en python para importar una libreria es simple, se usa import, pero para Perl... como es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Perl se emplea use.
Ejemplo:

```
 #hola.pl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use AlgunaLibreria;

    print "Hola\n";
```